# Calling post on a static handler within android activity

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, static, inner-classes

Following [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) article I modified my handler within the Activity class as follows:

```
private static class ActivityHandler extends Handler
{
    private final WeakReference<MyActivity> mActivity;

    public ActivityHandler(MyActivity activity)
    {
        mActivity = new WeakReference< MyActivity >(activity);
    }

    public final MyActivity getActivity()
    {
        return mActivity.get();
    }
}
```

The handler is initialised:

```
ActivityHandler handler = new ActivityHandler(this);
```

However, in several points of my activity logic I have to call post on this handler. So instead of this:

```
handler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                setSomeProperties();
            }
        });
```

I now do this:

```
handler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                MyActivity activity = handler.getActivity();
                if (activity != null)
                {
                    activity.setSomeProperties();
                }
            }
        });
```

Regardless of that change when I run the app and check the *hprof* file for leaked activities, I still get pointed to the `handler.post(new Runnable())` line. What am I doing wrong?

p.s. I have seen numerous examples overriding *handleMessage* on the handler, however, I haven't been able to make the connection with my case and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `Runnable` which is an anonymous class in your `Activity` and anonymous classes hold an implicit reference to the bound `Activity`.

Alex Lockwood has spoken about that also in the same article:

> To fix the memory leak that occurs when we instantiate the anonymous
>   Runnable class, we make the variable a static field of the class
>   (since static instances of anonymous classes do not hold an implicit
>   reference to their outer class)

To fix that (from the same article):

```
  /**
   * Instances of anonymous classes do not hold an implicit
   * reference to their outer class when they are "static".
   */
  private static final Runnable sRunnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() { /* ... */ }
  };
```

However, I would say, if the Runnable is not going to outlive the Activity's lifecycle (i.e. will get destroyed if the Activity gets destroyed), there is no need to change that to static fields.

From the same article:

> Avoid using non-static inner classes in an activity if instances of
>   the inner class could outlive the activity’s lifecycle.

Another solution from the comments section of the article:

> Instead of making the Runnable static, you could also just hold a
>   (non-static) reference to it and call
>   mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable) in onDestroy().

Comment: Thank you very much for this. So within the run method of the sRunnable how would I call setSomeProperties(), which is non-static?

Comment: Similar to `Handler`, you can create your own `Runnable` class inheriting from `Runnable` and have the `Activity` instance in a `WeakReference`. Now you can call `setSomeProperties()` using the `Activity` instance. Or the other solution that has been suggested in the comments section of the article is to call `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)` in `onDestroy()` of the `Activity` instead of making the `Runnable` static. You can do that also.

Comment: Thanks again, this has been most helpful.